# Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax is deprecated. Whats the alternative?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core, .net-core, deprecated, unobtrusive-ajax

I am updating packages in project codebase to `.net 6 (LTS)` and all the projects are updated and running successfully in my solution. One package `Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax` with version `3.2.6` when updating says its legacy and deprecated as part of the .NET Package Deprecation and I dont seem to find its alternative at all.

Can someone please guide what is its alternative or if I need to update it in my .net 6 based projects at all?
Thanks. Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like there is no newer version. Quote from the [source repository](https://github.com/aspnet/jquery-ajax-unobtrusive):

> ***IMPORTANT***: This repository is in maintenance mode. We do not work, nor
> plan to work on any new features. Only security and critical bug fixes
> will be worked on.

Stack Overflow is generally not for library recommendations. But even if we would want to recommend an alternative, we would have to know how/why you are using it currently.

Comment: Yes technically OP shouldn't be asking for alternatives, but I am thankful for the answer you provide because this pkg is something that comes out of the box with ASP.NET MVC solutions (at least for .NET Framework). Its a warning many will see and they may do what I did, and uninstall the package only to break all the forms or worse. I am not certain of the full extent of this pkg's use internally in the framework, but I at least know it plays a hand in the `AjaxHelper`'s functionality